# Pyspark: How to filter dataframe based on string and absence of prefix?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark, rlike

I have a pyspark dataframe like so with rows that have 'zodiac' and rows that have 'nonzodiac'

```
spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, '1234ESPNnonzodiac'), 
        (2, '1234ESPNzodiac'),
        (3, '963CNNnonzodiac'), 
        (4, '963CNNzodiac'),
    ],
    ['id', 'col1'] 
)
```

I can get all the nonzodiac rows like so:

```
nonzodiac_rows = df.where(f.col("col1").rlike("nonzodiac"))
```

But I'm having trouble returning only rows with 'zodiac' since doing something similar returns both zodiac and nonzodiac rows

```
zodiac_rows = df.where(f.col("col1").rlike("zodiac"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because nonzodiac contains zodiac substring. You need to write more strict regexp
For example add one more character:

```
zodiac_rows = df.where(f.col("col1").rlike("Nzodiac"))
```

Or restrict non before zodiac

```
zodiac_rows = df.where(f.col("col1").rlike("(?<!non)zodiac"))
```

Comment: `(?!non)zodiac` = `zodiac` because `zod` is not equal to `non`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the opposite of your "nonzodiac" `where` with the logical `not`operator

```
zodiac_rows = df.where(~f.col("col1").rlike("nonzodiac"))
```

Besides, there is the `filter` function that may help you in a different way

```
zodiac_rows = df.filter(~f.col('col1').contains('nonzodiac')).collect()
```